# Replace two String/Data using only one Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to replace the two strings and change it to `'-'`.

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| K      | V      |      1 | T      |        |
| O      | G      |      2 | O      | D      |
| B      |        |      3 | S      | A      |
| K      | H      |      4 | X      | Z      |
| +      | V      |      5 | +      | B      |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Under field5, I want to replace `'A'` and `'B'` to `'-'` but trying this code doesn't work:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(field5,'A', '-'), 'B', '-')),
    -> FROM tblPrelim;
```

Is there a way that I can replace it with only one query?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have an extra `),` in the query. Otherwise it works. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mW2xVsDswX4zAdQq8VT9Lk/0

Comment: @Barmar yes it works, but it does not change the strings inside the table

Comment: Of course. To change the strings in the table you need to use `UPDATE`, not `SELECT`

Comment: @Barmar should I Add UPDATE above replace? or just change SELECT to UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` to modify the table.

```
UPDATE tblPrelim
SET field5 = REPLACE(REPLACE(field5,'A', '-'), 'B', '-')
```

If the field always contains just a single character, so you're replacing the entire value rather than just a substring, you can simplify this to:

```
UPDATE tblPrelim
SET field5 = '-'
WHERE field5 IN ('A', 'B')
```

Comment: ohh I get it now. Thanks for that